# Traceback (most recent call last): File "code.py", line 2, in <module> from PIL import Image ImportError: No module named PIL

Tags: python, qr

quiero crear mis propios códigos QR usando este repositorio https://github.com/ss0028/qr-code-in-python pero me sale este error y como no tengo idea, no sé qué hacer. Por favor, si alguien me puede ayudar, ¿cómo puedo generar mi qr?

Por favor ayuda como puedo solucionar el error de la línea 2 ??? no tengo idea

texto

```
import pyqrcode
from PIL import Image

# Generate the qr code and save as png
qrobj = pyqrcode.create('https://google.com')
with open('test.png', 'wb') as f:
    qrobj.png(f, scale=10)

# Now open that png image to put the logo
img = Image.open('test.png')
width, height = img.size

# How big the logo we want to put in the qr code png
logo_size = 100

# Open the logo image
logo = Image.open('s.jpg')

# Calculate xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax to put the logo
xmin = ymin = int((width / 2) - (logo_size / 2))
xmax = ymax = int((width / 2) + (logo_size / 2))

# resize the logo as calculated
logo = logo.resize((xmax - xmin, ymax - ymin))

# put the logo in the qr code
img.paste(logo, (xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax))

img.show()


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "code.py", line 2, in <module>
    from PIL import Image
ImportError: No module named PIL
MBP-de-APPLE:hx apple$
```

Comment: Tu pregunta ahora está un poco mejor c: Solo falta que cambies las imagenes por texto y listo! Recuerda que si el código y el mensaje de error los pones como imagen, es más dificil ayudarte.

Comment: Ponte en nuestros zapatos y piensa lo que sería transcribir tu código para poderlo probar en nuestras computadoras.

Comment: Agrega el código _como texto, con formato_, con el botón que indica `{}`.

Comment: Tu problema quizá se deba a que tienes dos Python instalados e instalaste Pillow en una version y ejecutas el programa en otra. Por ejemplo, tienes dos versiones de Python (2.7 y 3.4) e instalaste pillow en la 3.4 pero tu programa se ejecuta en la 2.7 que NO tiene Pillow.

Comment: Por eso pregunto, tienes dos versiones de Python instaladas en tu pc?

Comment: @dante S si pero lo instale asi bro pip3 install Pillow.  esta mal ??? que hago entonces para quitar la otra versión, es que no tengo ni idea :,(

Comment: Si ya pusiste el código y el error como texto, las imágenes son innecesarias. ¿Por qué no las quitas?

Comment: ya las quite bro, por favor ayudame

Comment: No soy experto en como funciona Python en cuanto a abrir archivos por consola, pero proba con escribir en la consola `python3 code.py` a ver que pasa...

Comment: mira bro sale este error Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/apple/Desktop/hx/code.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pyqrcode
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyqrcode'

Comment: Creo que se te armó todo un lio con respecto a que instalaste un modulo en una version, otro en otra y asi... prueba ejecutar `pip3 install pyqrcode`, notese el 3 luego de pip para indicarle en que versión de Python instalarlo. Eso te instalara el modulo en el Python 3.x que tengas si no me equivoco.

Comment: Luego vuelve a probar con ejecutar el programa con `python3 code.py`. El 3 indica igual que con pip en que version de Python lo estás ejecutando

Comment: ya lo hice y mira lo que sale MBP-de-APPLE:hx apple$ pip3 install pyqrcode
Requirement already satisfied: pyqrcode in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-package. luego lo ejecute y salio esto Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/apple/Desktop/hx/code.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pyqrcode
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyqrcode'

Comment: Que cosa rara... La verdad no tengo ni idea de que puede ser la causa... Lo siento...